# How to upload images into mat file

Tags: matlab

I'm working in detecting diseases in fruits
I want to upload about a hundred of images of several diseases to .mat file and store them as number
ex: disease 1 = 0, disease 2 = 1...etc
and then use them as my training data for multiSVM
how could I implement it in matlab??
p.s i'm new to matlab

I have tried this code but it doesn't store any values:

```
function IMGDB = loadimages

BlossomEndRot_folder = 'Learning/';
FruitCracks_folder = 'Diseases/Fruit Cracks/Learning';

file_ext1 = '.png';
D1 = 0;
D2 = 1;
if exist('imagedb.mat','file')  
load imagedb;  
else  
IMGDB = cell (2,[]);  
end  
fprintf ('Loading Diseases');  
folder_content1 = dir ([BlossomEndRot_folder,'*',file_ext1]);
NumOfDiseaseImgs = size (folder_content1,1);  
for k=1:NumOfDiseaseImgs  
string = [BlossomEndRot_folder,folder_content1(k,1).name];  
image = imread(string);      
[m n] = size(image);  
f=0;  
for i=1:length(IMGDB)  
    if strcmp(IMGDB{1,i},string)  
        f=1;  
    end  
end  
if f==1  
    continue;  
end  
fprintf ('.');      
IMGDB {1,end+1}= string; 
IMGDB {2,end} = D1;    
end  
fprintf('\n');  
save imagedb IMGDB;
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the Stack Overflow [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the Matlab functions [imread](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) and [save](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html)

a stub of code for reading different images should look something like:

```
for im=1:N
  image = imread(['image' im '.jpg']);
  images(:,im) = image(:); % each image forms a column of the matrix "images"
end

save ('images.mat', images)
```

Comment: I have added the code I've been trying to use, but it doesn't store any values